# How to setup structure with SpringBoot and Angular2?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Angular2 with Springboot, but I can't set them together.

I first started a springboot project, and then tried to follow the Angular 2 Tour of Heroes by johnpapa and run `npm install`.

The structure looks like below:

[image: Structure]

I have the `/app` folder, and the `.js` are compiled to `resources/static/app/js`.

**Problems**:

1) The folder `resources/static/node_modules/` has lots of files. So when running `bootRun`, it gets really slow and sometimes can't even refresh the files. I believe I shouldn't put the node_modules there, but not sure..

2) `npm install` puts the files in `./node_modules` so currently I copied them to `static` folder. Should I just build the `node_modules` to `static`?

3) My structure looks *hacky*.. what is the best way to do it ?

How to set this structure? Also, please let me know if I should start using grunt/gulp or some other tool to make this easier.

Ps.: In case anyone is interested in the johnpapa's guide: [johnpapa's angular2 guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes)

Comment: My understanding was that the whole Angular 2 app should go under src/main/resources/static [or similar](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot). Does your current approach actually work?

Comment: The way I did, it works if I copy the `node_modules` to `static`, but the `bootRun` gets really slow and doesn't refresh the static content if it changes. I wanted to avoid putting the whole Angular 2 app so it doesn't publish unnecessary resources, but maybe that's the way I should it as you suggested..

Comment: I'm very interested in responses to your question, as I've been heading down this path too, but not yet fully implemented it.

Comment: Are you using [hot swapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) for your development code?

Comment: Consider separating the client code into a directory called "client".  All client side goes into that directory.  It is on the same level as "src".  Then use your js build tool of choice to place a dist version within the src/main/resources/static

Comment: The main point is don't try to mix a js build process with the java build process.  Join them afterwards.  I know some may offer wro4j.  The dev of Angular2 is way to fast to rely on wro4j keeping up.

Comment: Thanks @ccit-spence ! I'll follow your suggestions and it indeed makes sense to not mix both builds.. btw, do you use gulp?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407237/spring-boot-angular-2-structure

Comment: the `node_modules` directory should to be marked as ignored in your Gradle configuration

Comment: hi @FelipeS. I was use same directory stucture. when i build to new war then the node_module files missing in front end . please look this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378574/angular-2-integrate-with-spring-boot-as-single-war?noredirect=1#comment79718004_46378574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove `node_modules` from `static` folder. Your build process should bundle all the necessary modules. `node_modules` is used only during build.

2) Do not copy `node_modules` into static folder

3) Remove sources from `static` folder. That one is meant only for generated bundle + some static PROD files like `index.html`

Comment: Makes sense.. I'll take some time to learn some js build process.. thanks!!

Comment: Just adding here in case anyone falls into the same problem.. There is a nice link here teaching all of that! :) http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/24/creating-an-angular-2-build.html

Answer (score 1):

Try really cool **project builder** [Jhipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) ;)

Answer (score -1):

I shared on github a project that integrates Angular 2 with springboot. you can check here [Angular 2 with spring boot](https://github.com/mauriciolassakoski/angular_2_springboot)

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should really provide context to any links you provide in your answer so your answer can be used in standalone as if the link did not exist.