# Spring Boot + Angular 2 structure

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

In my project I want to use **`Spring Boot`** and **`Angular 2.`**

1. Structure of **`Spring Boot App`** is done from  [Spring Initializer](http://start.spring.io/).
2. Structure of **`Angular 2 App`** is done by **`Angular CLI`** tool (`ng new myfrontendapp`)

In **`Angular 1`** you can put your **`index.html`** into **public folder.**

In **`Angular 2`** the **`index.html`** is generated in **`src`** folder and I would like to keep that *structure*.

My question is what should I do to make **`index.html`** visible for **`Spring Boot`** and keep the *structure* generated by **`Angular CLI.`**

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Use your build tool to package the output of ng-cli (i.e. the content of the dist folder (not src)) into the public or static directory of the generated jar file.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution is to relocate build output of an Angular 2 project into Spring Boot **/static** or **/public** folder.

***2 Steps:***

1. Set the **outDir** in **.angular-cli.json** file:

[image]

2. in the **Angular 2 project root directory** type:

   ```
   ng build
   ```

---

*(! Please note that **this works for** **Angular 2 project generated in Angular CLI tool**, for Angular 2 project not created by Angular CLI tool, the outDir is edited in **tsconfig.json** file  )*

Answer (score 2):

Check my Spring Boot 2 and Angular 6 starter [here](https://github.com/milanhlinak/spring-boot-angular-starter).

Answer (score 2):

There's an framework called **JHipster**. It is easily to develop, deploy Spring Boot + Angular Apps.  Check out their sample and it would helpful.
The link is here: https://jhipster.github.io/

Jhipster supports both AngularJS and Angular, therefore you can find the both sources

Comment: This looks great. Thanks for tip.