# Angular 2 integrate with spring boot as single war

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

In my application working with angular js2 standalone. After integrating angular js2 build to spring boot web app files for deploy as single war. then getting error like this[image]

I tried two senarioes 
1) add npm intall and npm run build add as maven exucution goals.
2)Angularjs build manually by using commands that build out out copy to web app directry then build war.
These war put inito my local host then get these js missing problem. 
I'm new in angular2
My working environment 
Node : v8.1.2
npm -: v5.0.3
anular: 1.2

```
 "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "arrive": "^2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "chartist": "^0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "^0.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
    "domready": "^1.0.8",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "googleapis": "^19.0.0",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^1.8.3",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.7",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "pretty-error": "^2.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "^1.2.0",
    "validate": "^3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^1.10.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.73",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.0.0-rc.2.",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-pro-angular/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-pro-angular#readme",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": ""
}
```

Comment: can you look at this repo https://github.com/RobertRajcool/Angular2-Spring-Mvc

Comment: yup its just simple

Comment: i don't get any idea from that repo.

Comment: can you elaborate your software stack ? is it nodejs at backend and angularjs at frontend ?

Comment: Front end angukar js and back end java spring boot

Comment: @Araf just make sure all your frontend files go under src/main/webapp. it should serve your files. or else share the project structure

Comment: @Barath ya i checked it now. node_module is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the angular build successfully with same target which application you wish to embed. Suppose your spring boot application will be running in

> localhost:8080

the angular target should be same. Other wise it will be fail when you integrate with Spring.